# RecyclerView throwing IllegalArgumentException when EditText opened

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in a `LinearLayout`, which also contains an `EditText`.

The container Activity has `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"` set - so when the soft input opens, the `RecyclerView` shrinks because it's space has been readjusted.

Unfortunately, when you click the `EditText` causing the soft input to open, the following exception is thrown. I'm assuming this is another bug with the Android Support Library - can anyone confirm and perhaps suggest a work around?

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Scrapped or attached views may not be recycled. isScrap:false isAttached:true
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleViewHolderInternal(RecyclerView.java:4570)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.quickRecycleScrapView(RecyclerView.java:4642)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.removeAndRecycleScrapInt(RecyclerView.java:6636)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2811)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3011)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:581)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
```

Edit

I spent the last several hours slowly deconstructing my project, until the problem went away. I then reversed by changes after lunch. In a fit of insanity inducing madness, reversing the changes hasn't reintroduced the bug.

I am still 100% snookered by what this bug is, I begin to worry either I'm mad or there is an intermittent cause to this bug which has temporarily gone away :(

Comment: Check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477660/recyclerview-crashes-when-scrapped-or-attached-views-may-not-be-recycled

Comment: Yes, seen it, not related to this issue. Thanks for posting though. I'm not using any item animation, `android:animateLayoutChanges` has not been set and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` had no effect (and I have no idea why it should)

Comment: How about this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/40799494/1708390 ? I was facing the same issue and I think this resolved my problem