# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Scrapped or attached views may not be recycled. isScrap:false isAttached:true when scrolling down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: com.zipato.android.client.v2, PID: 24966
>                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Scrapped or attached views may not be recycled. isScrap:false isAttached:true
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleViewHolderInternal(RecyclerView.java:5736)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleView(RecyclerView.java:5680)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:289)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:336)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:349)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:356)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:387)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

App keeps crashing when I scroll down..

This is what my adapter looks like:

```
public class WalletAdapter extends SectioningAdapter {

static final boolean USE_DEBUG_APPEARANCE = false;


private List<Transaction> transactions;
private List<Section> sections = new ArrayList<>();

public WalletAdapter() {
}

private class Section {
    String alpha;
    List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
}

public List<Transaction> getTransactions() {
    return transactions;
}

public void setTransactions(List<Transaction> transactions) {
    this.transactions = transactions;
    sections.clear();

    String mDate = "31.12.2222";

    Section currentSection = null;
    for (Transaction transaction : transactions) {
        String date = parseDate(transaction.getCreatedDate());
        if (!date.equals(mDate)) {
            if (currentSection != null) {
                sections.add(currentSection);
            }

            currentSection = new Section();
            mDate = date;
            currentSection.alpha = String.valueOf(mDate);
        }

        if (currentSection != null) {
            currentSection.transactions.add(transaction);
        }
    }

    sections.add(currentSection);
    notifyAllSectionsDataSetChanged();
}

private String parseDate(Date date) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    String formattedDate = "";
    formattedDate = df.format(date);
    return formattedDate;
}

@Override
public int getNumberOfSections() {
    return sections.size();
}

@Override
public boolean doesSectionHaveHeader(int sectionIndex) {
    return sectionIndex == 0 || !parseDate(transactions.get(sectionIndex).getCreatedDate()).equals(parseDate(transactions.get(sectionIndex - 1).getCreatedDate()));
}

@Override
public boolean doesSectionHaveFooter(int sectionIndex) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public int getNumberOfItemsInSection(int sectionIndex) {
    return sections.get(sectionIndex).transactions.size();
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int itemUserType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wallet_item, parent, false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public HeaderViewHolder onCreateHeaderViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int headerUserType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wallet_header, parent, false);
    return new HeaderViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindItemViewHolder(SectioningAdapter.ItemViewHolder viewHolder, int sectionIndex, int itemIndex, int itemType) {
    super.onBindItemViewHolder(viewHolder, sectionIndex, itemIndex, itemType);
    Section section = sections.get(sectionIndex);
    ItemViewHolder holder = (ItemViewHolder) viewHolder;
    Transaction transaction = section.transactions.get(itemIndex);
    holder.description.setText(transaction.getDescription());
    holder.ammount.setText(String.valueOf(transaction.getAmount()));
    holder.time.setText(parseDate(transaction.getCreatedDate()));
    holder.total.setText(String.valueOf(transaction.getNewCredits()));
}


@Override
public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(SectioningAdapter.HeaderViewHolder viewHolder, int sectionIndex, int headerType) {
    super.onBindHeaderViewHolder(viewHolder, sectionIndex, headerType);
    Section s = sections.get(sectionIndex);
    HeaderViewHolder hvh = (HeaderViewHolder) viewHolder;

    if (USE_DEBUG_APPEARANCE) {
        hvh.itemView.setBackgroundColor(0x55ffffff);
        hvh.dateHeader.setText(pad(sectionIndex * 2) + s.alpha);
    } else {
        hvh.dateHeader.setText(s.alpha);
    }
}

private String pad(int spaces) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
        b.append(' ');
    }
    return b.toString();
}

public class HeaderViewHolder extends SectioningAdapter.HeaderViewHolder {

    TextView dateHeader;

    public HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        dateHeader = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    }
}

public class ItemViewHolder extends SectioningAdapter.ItemViewHolder {

    TextView description;
    TextView time;
    TextView ammount;
    TextView total;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        ammount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ammount);
        total = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.new_credits);
    }
}
```

}

This is my activity's xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.zipato.appv2.activities.WalletActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And the code inside activity onCreate:

```
 recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I tried calling adapter.setHasStableIds(true); in my activity and setting             android:focusableInTouchMode="true" inside recyclerView xml but nothing helps

Comment: Can you add the xml where the recycler is displayed?

Comment: Did you had a chance to check some answers from here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477660/recyclerview-crashes-when-scrapped-or-attached-views-may-not-be-recycled

Comment: yes.. I don't have android:animateLayoutChanges in my recyclerView xml, I tried setting android:focusableInTouchMode="true", attachToRoot is false... Maybe changing getItemId() method could help, but I'm not really sure how to fix it

Comment: do you have `</LinearLayout>` at the end of the xml file?

Comment: yes yes.. it wouldn't compile without it :)

Comment: Ofcourse, I'm just asking since it's not visible in the snippet. I think you should debug one of these methods and see if they are returning right values: getNumberOfSections, doesSectionHaveHeader, doesSectionHaveFooter and getNumberOfItemsInSection.

Comment: Yeah, my bad.. I debugged them and everything is ok..when i debug and scroll, everything is fine, but when I'm not in debug, when i want to scroll it fast, it crashes...

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, didn't find what causes it though... seems like a bug in a support lib.
You can try disabling item prefetch for layout manager:

```
layoutManager.setItemPrefetchEnabled(false);
```

Solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

overwrite `getItemId` method in your adapter, like below

```
 @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: Should I do some more stuff here other than just returning position?

Comment: Note that you should call `setHasStableIds(true);` in the adapter's constructor when you use this approach (see the super-class getItemId documentation for more info).